# How to install modules in Docker (Selenium, Python)

Tags: python, selenium, docker, module, warnings

I have installed Selenium to Python 3 with "pip install selenium", and now I want to install the selenium module to Docker as well (in order to run my python script in a Docker container).

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install selenium

RUN mkdir localhosttest

COPY GetFilesHere/localhost.py /docker/localhosttest/localhost.py

CMD python /docker/localhosttest/localhost.py
```

However when Docker reaches the "RUN pip install selenium" line I get a warning message:
"WARNING: Retrying (Retry/total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=none, status=None)) after connection broken by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(..."

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks proxy issue , your proxy server is not able to connect. Try to build this without proxy server it should work.
I ran the same docker file worked for me (with no proxy), or debug the issue for proxy sever and fix it.